# Unique $\varphi$ assigning integer to finite CW complex, $\varphi(X) = \varphi(Y)$ if $X \simeq Y$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is a followup to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999673/assigning-integer-to-finite-cw-complex-such-that-following-hold).

> For each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, is there a unique function $\varphi$ assigning an integer to each finite CW complex, such that the following hold?
>
> 1. $\varphi(X) = \varphi(Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.
> 2. $\varphi(X) = \varphi(A) + \varphi(X/A)$ if $A$ is a subcomplex of $X$.
> 3. $\varphi(S^0) = n$.

[Mike Miller](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/98602/mike-miller) provided the following answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1999735/386130).

> Yes. Of course, such a function exists; let $\varphi_n(X) = n\tilde{\chi}(X)$, where $\tilde{\chi}$ is the reduced Euler characteristic. Your property 2 follows from the reduced homology long exact sequence.
>
> Call a function of your kind $\varphi_n$.
>
> 1) $\varphi_n(A \vee B) = \varphi_n(A) + \varphi_n(B)$. You can always subdivide the CW structures on $A \vee B$ so that their wedge is a CW complex with $A$ and $B$ given as subcomplexes. Then $B = (A\vee B)/A$.
>
> 2) $\varphi_n(S^k) = (-1)^kn$. This follows because if $S^{k-1} \subset S^k$ is the equator, then $S^k/S^{k-1} = S^k \vee S^k$. So $\varphi_n(S^k) = \varphi_n(S^{k-1}) + 2\varphi_n(S^k)$. So $\varphi_n(S^k) = -\varphi_n(S^{k-1})$.
>
> 3) Let $X^k$ be the $k$-skeleton of $X$. Suppose we know that for CW complexes of dimension at most $k$, $\varphi_n(X) = n\tilde{\chi}(X)$. Then if $X$ is of dimension $(k+1)$, $\varphi_n(X) = \varphi_n(X^k) + \varphi_n(\vee_\ell S^{k+1}) = (-1)^{k+1}\ell n$, where $\ell$ is the number of $(k+1)$-cells in $X$. But the reduced homology is precisely the same as the alternating sum of the number of cells in each dimension, minus one. So the result follows.

**Question.** For such a function $\varphi$, does it follow that $\varphi(X) = \varphi(Y)$ if $X \simeq Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 2.44 in [Hatcher's book](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) states that $$\chi(X)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\operatorname{rank} H_n(X).$$ Now suppose $X\simeq Y$ are finite CW complexes. By the homotopy invariance of singular homology (Hatcher, Corollary 2.11), there are isomorphisms $H_n(X)\cong H_n(Y)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$. In particular, the ranks of these groups are the same, so $$\chi(X)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\operatorname{rank} H_n(X)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\operatorname{rank} H_n(X)=\chi(Y).$$

The answer of [Mike Miller](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999673/assigning-integer-to-finite-cw-complex-such-that-following-hold/1999735#1999735) tells you that $\varphi_n=n\tilde\chi$ is the unique function satisfying your requirements. By the above, this function satisfies $$\varphi_n(X)=n\tilde\chi(X)=n(\chi(X)-1)=n(\chi(Y)-1)=n\tilde\chi(Y)=\varphi_n(Y)$$ and we're done.